# SyntaxError - node_modules/react-native/Libraries/polyfills/error-guard.js: Missing semicolon. (14:4) on running jest in react native library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm trying to setup jest for a react native library but I'm getting the below error

```
SyntaxError: react-native/Libraries/polyfills/error-guard.js: Missing semicolon. (14:4)

      12 | let _inGuard = 0;
      13 |
    > 14 | type ErrorHandler = (error: mixed, isFatal: boolean) => void;
         |     ^
      15 | type Fn<Args, Return> = (...Args) => Return;
```

**react-native version** : 0.61.5

**app.js**

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';

function sum(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
module.exports = sum;
```

**app.test.js**

```
const sum = require('./app');

test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
  expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(3);
});
```

**jest.config.js**

```
module.exports ={
    preset : 'react-native',
    transformIgnorePatterns: [
        '/node_modules/(?!(@react-native|react-native)/).*/'
    ]
}
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
    "presets": ["react-native"]
}
```

I tried various solutions suggested like adding transformIgnorePatterns but to no avail. can someone help me here ?

Comment: Not sure if this can help, but this looks like a TypeScript file, but with the **.js** extension.

Answer (score 9):

It worked for me after I changed the `.babelrc` file to `babel.config.js`.

Comment: Do not understand why this works

Comment: This really should be fixed.

Comment: According to one source: `Converting your .babelrc to a babel.config.js file sometimes helps because a babel.config.js file is evaluated in your project's root, whereas .babelrc is evaluated relative to the file being compiled. This might make a difference when dealing with dependencies outside of your source code.`

Answer (score 4):

It also worked for me after I changed the `.babelrc` file to `babel.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
    presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
};
```

`package.json`

```
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.67.4",
[...]
"@babel/core": "7.18.0",
```

Answer (score 1):

I could finally fix this problem after a long struggle:

As Daniel said in the answer above we need to change the .babelrc file to babel.config.js. In addition to that we have to follow the below steps:

1. Define `presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset']` in the babel.config.js file.
2. Add following packages to the package.json file: `"@testing-library/jest-native": "^4.0.5"`, and `"babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1"`

Answer (score 1):

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"],
};
```

Error solved after adding babel.config.js in the block root directory

Comment: Wasn't this exact same answer already provided above?